# The Wizard's Spellbook

Tags: riddle, language

One day in the 1620's, you discover a cave. Deep in the cave, you discover a door. Behind the door, you discover a hall. Deep in the hall is the wizard's house. Lit by candles, a large leather bound book lies on a table. Strange power is coming out of it, and the nearby shelves rustle quietly like leaves in the wind. The book is titled *Mage Potens*. The dark brown book has old yellow pages, and the text is written in a feather pen. To its right, an ink bottle with a feather quill sits, as if ready to write. You reach to grab the book, but find that you can't. It's enchanted. The quill leaps out of the ink bottle, and a piece of old parchment flutters down from the top of a shelf. The feather starts writing in old English. *Thine larcener, your assay hath failed, for aught valuable hath been hidden. Avaunt.* Behind you, candles flicker and suddenly go out. The only candles remaining are four candles, in front of the book. Some strange force makes you reach out and grab the quill. The book flips open to an empty page. Suddenly, you feel compelled to write. Without knowing what you are writing, the words fly across the page. You write,

> Luran or lordling, hearken now, for thine expiry mayhap be soon. Hath thine corse in thine garth, for thine hath assayed to larcen mine power. Avaunt, thief, avaunt unless thine hath a speck of smart. Thine larcener, if dare you not, leave before thy glim does fade. If dare ye to break my spell, thine shall answer a riddle.

You watch the words fly across the page. Suddenly, you drop the quill. The spell seems to have faded. Suddenly, the rustling gets much louder, and a candle begins to glow. On the wall, you watch with horror as words begin to appear on the wall. The ink scares you. It is scarlet. It reads,

> To break thine spell,
>
> and earn thy gold,
>
> you will be rewarded
>
> at least tenfold.
>
> A prefix meaning "Used to be",
>
> Followed by the letter P,
>
> My favorite word for Unity,
>
> The first letter of my word for "near",
>
> First two letters of when score is equal,
>
> The only shortest article.
>
> Now, young plunderer, if you dare,
>
> Speak said word aloud, but if it is dear
>
> To be out of here, then continue with my riddle.
>
> A word for good,
>
> The beginning of the middle,
>
> And then you have your spell.

After you finish reading, the candle starts to flicker. Before it goes out, what is the spell to free you?

Hint:

> The spell may not necessarily be English words! The title of the book was *Mage Potens*.

Comment: Interesting. Good writer.

Answer (score 4):

A slight stretch:

> Exponential Growth

To break thine spell,

and earn thy gold,

you will be rewarded

at least tenfold.

> Exponential Growth would mean increasing exponentially (aka "rewarded at least tenfold")

A prefix meaning "Used to be",

> **EX**- (e.g. ex-boyfriend)

Followed by the letter P,

> **P**

My favorite word for Unity,

> **ONE** (e.g. "act as one")

The first letter of my word for "near",

> **N**igh (Old English for "near")

First two letters of when score is equal,

> **TI**e

The only shortest article.

> **AL** (the Arabic definite article, aka the shortest definite article)

Now, young plunderer, if you dare,

Speak said word aloud

> **EXPONENTIAL**

but if it is dear

To be out of here, then continue with my riddle.

A word for good,

> **GROW** ? This one is admittedly a little shakey

The beginning of the middle,

> **TH**e middle

And then you have your spell.

Answer (score 3):

Based on [@CaptainPlanet's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/65931/44221), I'm going to go with

> Exponential Wealth

Reasoning:

> Starting with Exponential the same way CaptainPlanet did,

A word for good

> Well

The beginning of the middle

> th -> well + th = wellth, which when spoken aloud becomes Wealth

---

> Alternately, instead of Well, could use Weal, which seems to be an Old English root for wealth

Comment: Ah, I bet this is it. Nice alley-oop :)

Comment: Very close-ish!

Answer (score 2):

Is it

> Exponende a(d) finem (afaict these are all Latin words, ad finem means to the end and exponende means exposing)

The first part built off of @CaptainPlanet's answer, with

scores matched:

> deuce instead of tie, making the first 2 letters de

shortest article:

> a (ad may be an article in a different language)

For the second:

A word for good:

> fine

The beginning of the middle:

> m

Comment: Hmm, getting closer! You're right about Latin, but not the Latin text.

Comment: hmm, rot13(svarz) fits the word for good better but the overall phrase doesn't make a whole lot of sense

Comment: Well, have you considered that the first word may also be different? Also, rot13(svarz) is correct.